# How to calculate probability from transform function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

In my book I found an interesting question, given the transform function (moment generating function) of random variable $X$:$$M_X(s)=\frac{1}{2^4}\left (\left (e^s+1\right )^2\left (e^s+3\right )\right ).$$I want to compute $\mathbb{P}(X>2)$, which is equal to $1-\mathbb{P}(X\leq 2)$.

I know that I can use $M_X(s)$ to calculate expected value, but how to use it to calculate probability function.

Plus the question doesn't say anything if $X$ is continuous or discrete...

Comment: Most likely your MGF is defined $E[e^{sX}]$. If $X$ is discrete with $k$ possible values then we get $E[e^{sX}] = \sum_{i=1}^k e^{sx_i}P[X=x_i]$. So if you have such a sum of exponentials then you know you have a discrete random variable with a finite number of possible values. Alternatively you can note that if $X=Y+Z$ for $Y, Z$ independent then $M_X(s) = M_Y(s)M_Z(s)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using
$$M_{\text{Bernoulli}(p)}(t)=p\left(\frac{1-p}p+e^t\right)$$
and the fact that summing independent random variables multiplies their mgfs, we find that

- $M_{\text{Bernoulli}(1/2)}(t)=\frac12(e^t+1)$
- $M_{\text{Bernoulli}(1/4)}(t)=\frac14(e^t+3)$

so $X$ is the sum of two $\text{Bernoulli}(1/2)$ variables and one $\text{Bernoulli}(1/4)$ variable, all independent. Its realisation is greater than $2$ iff it is $3$, so $\mathbb P(X>2)=\frac12×\frac12×\frac14=\frac1{16}$.

Comment: I just proved that it's $1/24$ which of us is correct and which one is wrong. How I did my calculations? Well for discrete random variable we know that $M_X(t)=E(e^{Xt})=\sum P_X(x)*e^{xt}$ simplifying the expression in my quesiton gives me $3/24 * e^{0s} + 7/24 * e^{1s} + 5/24 * e^{2s} + 1/24 * e^{3s}$ which means: $P(X>2)=P(X=3)=1/24$

Comment: @zoro How could you mistake $2^4$ for $24$?

Comment: IDK LOL, but thanks